# Vectorized cosine similarity calculation in Python

Tags: python, matrix, cosine-similarity

I have two large sets of vectors, `A` and `B`. Each element of `A` is a 1-dimensional vector of length 400, with float values between -10 and 10. For each vector in `A`, I'm trying to calculate the cosine similarities to all vectors in `B` in order to find the top 5 vectors in `B` that best match the given `A` vector. For now I'm looping over all of `A`, and looping over all of `B`, calculating the cosine similarities one-by-one with SciPy's `spatial.distance.cosine(a, b)`. Is there a faster way to do this? Perhaps with matrices?

Answer (score 7):

You can transform each vector first in its unit-vector (by dividing it
through its length). Then the distance formular simplifies to

```
 d = 1 - e_v * e_w

 with e_v = v / ||v||_2 , e_w = w / ||v||_2
```

which is faster to calculate.

Probably more faster is to use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(XA, XB, 'cosine')`.
You need to build a matrix from the sets of vectors (pseudo-code):

```
XA=np.array([vecA1,vecA2,...,vecA400])
XB=np.array([vecB1,vecB2,...,vecB400])
distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(XA, XB, 'cosine')
```

Comment: Thank you, using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()` is much faster. For those interested, the docs are here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist

Answer (score 6):

This is a NAIVE no loop, no overhead(?) implementation of what you need...

```
from np.linalg import norm
res = 1 - np.dot(A/norm(A, axis=1)[...,None],(B/norm(B,axis=1)[...,None]).T)
```

Could you please benchmark it on a subset of your data and let us know if it's faster than scipy's cosine distance?

---

ps, `axis=1` above is based on the assumption that your vectors are stored row wise,

```
print A
# [[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 400]
#  [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 401]
```

etc

---

#### Comments

```
In [79]: A = np.random.random((2,5))

In [80]: A
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0.2917865 ,  0.89617367,  0.27118045,  0.58596817,  0.05154168],
       [ 0.61131638,  0.2859271 ,  0.09411264,  0.57995386,  0.09829525]])

In [81]: norm(A,axis=1)
Out[81]: array([ 1.14359988,  0.90018201])

In [82]: norm(A,axis=1)[...,None]
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1.14359988],
       [ 0.90018201]])

In [83]: A/norm(A,axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-707fa10dc673> in <module>()
----> 1 A/norm(A,axis=1)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (2,) 

In [84]: A/norm(A,axis=1)[...,None]
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0.25514737,  0.78364267,  0.23712878,  0.51238915,  0.04506968],
       [ 0.67910309,  0.31763254,  0.10454846,  0.64426289,  0.10919486]])

In [85]: norm(A/norm(A,axis=1)[...,None], axis=1)
Out[85]: array([ 1.,  1.])

In [86]:
```

The session above is for explaining the normalisation procedure,
when we have the normalised matrices A' and B' we take the dot product (we have to transpose the B' matrix of course) and the result is a matrix whose element `j, j`
is the dot product of NORMALISED vectors A_i and B_j, we subtract from `1` this matrix and we have a matrix of cosine distances. Or so I hope...

#### Test & Benchmark

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                              

In [2]: from numpy.linalg import norm as n

In [3]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

In [4]: A = np.random.random((100,400))

In [5]: B = np.random.random((100,400))

In [6]: C = np.array([[cosine(a,b) for b in B] for a in A])

In [7]: c = 1.0 - np.dot(A/n(A,axis=1)[:,None],(B/n(B,axis=1)[:,None]).T)

In [8]: np.max(C-c)
Out[8]: 8.8817841970012523e-16

In [9]: np.min(C-c)
Out[9]: -8.8817841970012523e-16

In [10]: %timeit [[cosine(a,b) for b in B] for a in A];
1 loops, best of 3: 1.3 s per loop

In [11]: %timeit 1.0 - np.dot(A/n(A,axis=1)[:,None],(B/n(B,axis=1)[:,None]).T)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.28 ms per loop

In [12]:
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this solution is doing? It's not clear to me how this gives me the cosine similarities between all vectors in `A` and `B`.

Comment: @alavin89 The _cosine distance_ is  the complement to 1 of the [_cosine similarity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).  In turns the cosine similarity is the cosine of the angle _a_ between two vectors, that we compute from the relationship dot(v1, v2) = mod(v1) mod(v2) cos(_a_). --- In your Q you reference [`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`: here it is its documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) and also [the source code](http://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L267).

Comment: instead of using `norm(A,axis=1)[...,None]` is more clear to use `norm(A,axis=1, keepdims=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[fast approximate nearest neighbor search](https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib)" instead, which is faster but less accurate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34525821)